# Is there any solution to notify Kafka message producer to send message again

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Suppose that kafka message producer send an event message to a topic. And then a consumer process this event message. However, this consumer process it throw exception because business error, so he want to let the message producer know it and resent again.

Are there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should, generally, not create such coupling between producers and consumers.

If a consumer fails to read a message then it ideally shouldn't commit that offset. If the record didn't expire in Kafka, then there's no need for the producer to send anything as data is still in the broker, so having the consumer application be restarted will attempt to read the failed offsets again.

Comment: Well, my scenario is ask the producer to send again, with different content (maybe something need to be corrected). But it is also fine, would I know that, for your case here, how if I don't restart and consume the message again?

Comment: I don't understand that question, but programmatically, Kafka has no such feature. You'd need to setup your consumer as a producer ,and your producer as a consumer , or use some other RPC channel to communicate between the two. In most scenarios, the producer code is written by completely different teams, in which case, you'd actually need to communicate with other developers

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to never miss a message but might duplicate the occasional message, you can use delivery semantic "at-least-once".

Comment: I think there is a misunderstand here. The scenario is, producer successfully send a message already, but consumer handle the message with business exception, and request producer to send again.

Comment: there is no need for the producer to send a message again because kafka change the offset and message will be send to the consumer again.

Comment: if i understand your question correctly you want to edit a produced message and it is not possible in kafka but what you can do is to send a key so the message goes to the same partition in order and to correct the business send a new message and consume the last message that represents your business in the right way in this case your just interested in the last message.